# How can we move a journey to another folder using REST/SOAP API in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am looking for a solution where I can move a journey from one folder into another folder using REST/SOAP API in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an API you can use to move a journey to a folder that has already been created:

```
Host: {{your_rest_base_uri}}
POST  /interaction/v1/interactions/categories/{{category_id}}
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Body: { "definitionIds": ["JB_DEFINITION_ID_1", "JB_DEFINITION_ID_2"] }
```

The response also includes "hasErrors" and "categoryExists" which might be useful as some sort of verification. 
However, I'm not quite sure if you need extra permissions other than "journeys_read" in the scope.

Comment: Also, as you can see in the answer you can move more than one journeys at a time.

Comment: Hi Ted ,Thanks for the code snippet provided above, Is Journey DefinationID and JourneyID same ?? we are also getting error as "    "errorcode": 0,
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type"" when executing above code.

Comment: @OmkarKagati You can retrieve the journey definition id via the link of the journey. e.g. if the journey link is https://mc.sxx.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Journey%20Builder/%23a0000000000000000000000000000000 then the journey definition id would be a0000000000000000000000000000000